# remove text from string and return the removed part

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Is there is any way to remove a text from string and return the removed part, for example

```js
var foo = "Hello world!";
var bar = foo.remove("world!");

console.log(foo); // "Hello "
console.log(bar); // "world!"
```

All I can think of is

```js
var foo = "Hello world!";
var bar;
foo = foo.replace("world!",function(m){
  bar = m;
  return "";
});
```

But I hope there is a better way to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the value of `bar`, so there is no need to compute it.

```
var foo = "Hello world!";
var bar = "world!";
foo = foo.replace(bar,"");
```

Comment: you are right; my bad I should have used Regex instead of string in the example, I just wanted to make a simple example

Comment: ill accept this since it answers the question

Comment: Did you mean if the `bar` was a regex ? in that case you can use `foo=foo.replace(new RegExp(bar,"g"),"");`

Comment: Although that could replace various words, and the `bar` would turn into an array.

Comment: [Here is](https://gist.github.com/mostapha/fe84eeee9519257ca1b1521ec393d95c) what I'm trying to do , Thanks anyway

Comment: For that problem i believe you are using the best possible option. However if it were me i would change the arquitecture from `string`s as code to `Map`s. And refrain from using eval unless there were really obvious necessities. [Some reasons why im commenting this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)

Comment: They also have foo, so it cna be optimized even more, if that was really the goal...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.match`.

```js
var foo = "Hello World!";
foo = foo.match("World!")[0];
```

Comment: there are two variable, this will not edit the first one